# dataframe to list by column with row names

Tags: r

I am trying to list elements of a dataframe (ordered by column) with row.names using `dplyr`

```
temp_df<-data.frame(c(1,3),c(2,4))
colnames(temp_df)<-c("col1","col2")
row.names(temp_df)<-c("r1","r2")
temp_df                    

require(dplyr)
temp_df%>%split(colnames(temp_df))
```

Goal

```
col1
r1 1
r2 3
col2
r1 2
r2 4
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It's kind of an odd thing to do.

Comment: See my answer for a possible solution. Could you elaborate on the larger problem you're trying to solve? I agree with @RichardScriven; your current desired output looks a bit odd.

Comment: I have a correlation matrix and I am trying to view a vertical list of correlations for each column, rather than the dataframe they are currently in.

Comment: Fair enough. Was there any particular reason to use 'dplyr'?

Comment: Not really, I have been using it a lot lately, but couldn't seem to find a way to do this using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use base-R for this, as you're simply extracting columns from a dataframe. Using 'drop=FALSE' ensures the preservation of row names. I do hope this was your intended output (a list of one-column dataframes).

```
#create vector of columns
mycols <- colnames(temp_df)
names(mycols) <- mycols

#extract data
res <- lapply(mycols, function(x){temp_df[,x, drop=F]})

>res
$col1
   col1
r1    1
r2    3

$col2
   col2
r1    2
r2    4
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude NA values from showing up in the list?

Comment: You can use `na.omit`. (`na.omit(temp_df[,x,drop=F]))`)