# R - split dataframe into list by column while retaining a second column, then rename list elements by col name

Tags: r

Two parted question. The first part seems so simple but I must be missing it.
I would like to split a dataframe by column, but, in these data, retain the `state` column in each list element.

Then ideally I would like to rename the list elements as the column names and standardize the column name in the list element.

Easier to show:

```
df <- data.frame(state = rep(letters[1:3], each = 2),
                 score1 = rnorm(6, 1, 1),
                 score2 = rnorm(6, 10, 1))
```

What I would love to end up with is

```
$`score1`
   state      value 
1      a  0.3406192
2      a  0.9598098
3      b  0.8813060
4      b  0.9803431
5      c  0.5143215
6      c -0.4401475 

$`score2`
   state      value
1      a  10.332035
2      a  11.572288
3      b  8.930529
4      b  10.916287
5      c  9.405007
6      c  12.181647
```

[This SO post is very close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581669/dataframe-to-list-by-column-with-row-names) but I thought there may be a better way to keep the one `state` column while splitting out the other columns.

The end goal is to nest these by state into a tibble, summarise each to get the mean and sd by state, then use `purrr::map()` to run a series of models on each (hence the column name standardization). A tidyverse suggestion would be great if someone comes up with something, but other solutions are cool too.

Comment: The wording of the question is bad, so any suggestions or edits for clarity would be very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the dataframe in long format and use `split`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('score')) %>%
  split(.$name) %>%
  map(~.x %>% select(-name))

#$score1
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  state  value
#  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 a      1.58 
#2 a      0.567
#3 b     -0.313
#4 b      0.756
#5 c      0.236
#6 c      1.05 

#$score2
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  state value
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 a      9.93
#2 a      9.96
#3 b     12.2 
#4 b      9.41
#5 c      9.40
#6 c      9.97
```

You can also use `group_split` and avoid the `map` step but it doesn't give the list names (`score1`, `score2`) in the output.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('score')) %>%
  group_split(name, .keep  = FALSE)
```

Comment: How can I retain the column name in dataframe of the list i.e., instead of column name `value` it would like to have `score1`.

Comment: If you remove the `map` statement i.e `map(~.x %>% select(-name))` or if you are using `group_split` remove `.keep = FALSE` which should keep the `name` column in the output @NadPat

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
 # Reshape the data.frame to long format: long_df => data.frame
long_df <- reshape(
  df,
  direction = "long",
  varying = which(names(df) != "state"),
  idvar = "state",
  v.names = "value",
  timevar = "score_no",
  times = names(df)[names(df) != "state"],
  new.row.names = seq_len((sum(names(df) != "state") * nrow(df)))
)
# Allocate some memory: df_list => empty list: 
df_list <- vector("list", length(unique(long_df$score_no)))

# Split the data.frame into a list: df_list => list of data.frames
df_list <- split(long_df[,names(long_df) != "score_no"], long_df$score_no)
```